# sshd log verbose filter out specific user

Tags: ssh, logs, users, sshd

I would to filter out one specific user that very often connect to my servers via sshd.
I no more want to see into ssh's logs the connexion of this user.

Is it possible to do that ? to keep the actual verbose level and to just modify the verbosity for one user ? Maybe into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?

Thanks

Comment: You can set up a `rsyslog` filter checking for the user’s name in messages using the `security` facility. You’ll still get messages associated with the connection however, such a session disconnected. Completely dismissing all log would be hard since a connection message is logged before the username appears. You could possibly use a buffer to catch all messages and not write anything until you’re sure your user is not involved.

Comment: Another option is to block the user from port 22 then run a second `sshd` on another port. Limit that instance to your user and turn logging off.